How to backpressure Node.js TCP server?
Node.js seems to automatically accept() all connections on a listening socket.
This is an issue as it can lead to unbounded memory expansion.
Funnily enough, the listen() methods all take a backlog parameter, even though the TCP connection backlog is essentially infinite.
Can I limit the accept() for Node.js sockets?

The backlog in listen says nothing about the total number of accepted/established connections currently in use. It only is about the amount of connections which can be established by the OS kernel before accept is called by the application. What you might want to look at is agent.maxSockets instead.

@SteffenUllrich, correct but per my understanding the backlog is practically infinite, because Node.js automatically accepts every connection. Also, agent is for HTTP clients not TCP (or HTTP) servers.

Again, the backlog is only for describing what the kernel can accept w/o nodejs accepting. The backlog can be 1 - but nodejs can still accept "infinite" connections (limited by system ressources and process limits - see rlimit). So the backlog parameter is irrelevant here and what you describe is also not a "backlog", it is accepted and established connections. Maybe server.maxConnections is what you are looking for?
